# По какому принципу строится сложный LEFT JOIN в PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

по какому принципу строится сложный лефт джойн

предположим 4 таблицы

```
select * from t1, t4 
left join t2 on t2.id = t1.t2_id  
left join t3 on t3.id = t1.t3_id
where t1.name = 12 and t2.parent = 3  and t4.id = 100
```

соответственно это не рабочий скл.

примеры в доке очень простые http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html и не дают понимания

т.е. каков правильный синтаксис. куда загонять лефт джойн? в конец? в середину?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. В чем именно вы видите проблему и что хотите видеть в ответе?

Comment: мне вообще не понятно, что должно оказаться в ответе

Comment: Найдите книжку `undershanding sql` или `понимание sql`. Правда не знаю есть ли там `join`, раньше не было. Но книжка полезная особенно для нубов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В PostgreSQL оператор *запятая* работает не полностью аналогично оператору *JOIN* и использование *LEFT JOIN* после использования запятой несет массу ограничений. Например в вышеприведенном запросе в *LEFT* вы могли бы ссылаться на *t4*, но не на *t1*. В принципе в конкретном случае перестановка `_t4_, _t1_` вместо `t1 ,t4` должна была бы помочь. Но в общем случае если вы хотите использовать в запросе хоть один JOIN вам стоит отказаться от использования *запятой*:

```
select *
  from t1
 CROSS join t4
  left join t2 on t2.id = t1.t2_id  
  left join t3 on t3.id = t1.t3_id
 where t1.name = 12 and t2.parent = 3  and t4.id = 100
```

Кроме того, так как у вас нет условия соединения таблиц *t1* и *t4* (вы полностью перемножаете их содержимое) то вместо обычного *JOIN* следует использовать *CROSS JOIN*.

Answer (score 0):

если не прав то поправьте. идея вроде такова

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT *
   FROM t1,
        t4
   WHERE t4.id = 100
     AND t1.id = t4.id ) t1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT *
   FROM t2
   WHERE t2.parent = 3) t2 ON t2.id = t1.t2_id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT *
   FROM t3
   WHERE t3.parent = 3) t3 ON t3.id = t1.t3_id
```

т.е. джойны как модули подключаются к основному запросу

Comment: Это не ответ, а часть вопроса, точнее вашего представления о том что происходит. Перенесите в вопрос. И сформулируйте, в чем ваш вопрос, что именно является проблемой

Comment: каков правильный синтаксис вот вопрос. и дан возможный вариант как ответ

Comment: А что, в вопросе синтаксис разве неправильный, не выполняется и возвращает ошибку?

Comment: мой запрос немного хитрее https://gist.github.com/des1roer/4e0c4cc9a86d2be67c6eebf83eb42e2c и да в этом виде не работает

Comment: Отлично, мы подбираемся к исходной проблеме. Почему не работает, на что жалуется, какие ошибки выводит? Попробуйте упростить запрос и выяснить в чем ошибка, и тогда уже по ней задать вопрос здесь.

Comment: да нет я решил проблему. вполне возможно есть и другой синтаксис. просто пытался использовать лефт джойн внутри запроса, а пришлось все оборачивать в селект и добавлять в конце